# Basic PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I have the following Array:

```
$a = array();
$handle = fopen('test.csv','r');
while (!feof($handle)){
    $a = fgetcsv($handle,",");
}
fclose($handle);
echo $a[100];
```

Accompanied with the following CSV file (test.csv):

```
100,1245
500,111
600,12
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 100
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have two columns, I want the first column to be the key, and the second column the value. I would then expect to have $a[100] return 1245. What am I missing? Why is this so hard?

**EDIT**

I want the first column to be the key and the second column to be the value. HOW do I achieve that goal? THAT is the question. Please don't get side tracked...

Comment: `$a[100]` does not exist. the array contains 3 items only, so only `$a[0]`, `$a[1]`, and `$a[2]`, are valid. if you're creating a key/value array (whatever that's called in PHP), then use `$a["100"]` instead.

Comment: To debug the array use `var_dump` or `print_r` for your reference.

Comment: 100 is not the key, it's a value. Keys will be automatically assigned from 0.

Comment: @HighCore why does it only contain 3 items? Why does it not contain 3 keys and 3 values?

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
$final  =   array();
foreach($a as $val){
    $var    =   explode(',',$val);
    $final[$var[0]] =   $var[1];
}

echo $final[100];
```

**Output:** 1245

Comment: where does this fall in context of the code that I have already shown above? @Ronser

Comment: this line $final[$var[0]] = $var[1]; throws this error Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: This is not a solution as I get an undefined offset error.

Comment: just use `print_r($a); exit;` below `fclose($handle);` and post the result

Comment: Array ( [0] => 600 [1] => 12 )

Comment: any ideas on the above post? Looks like it is only saving the last value of the CSV.